Would it be worth to create the "pun" tag?
Considering this question A magma-related lava pun, what do you think about creating the new tag pun, since I think the verb tag doesn't fit very well with the question.
I'm also not sure that the idioms tags matches with this kind of questions.
Comments and suggestions are welcome.

To encourage participation of the community on this issue, I've labelled this post as "fatured", so it's visible on the main site.

In principle, it seems OK to me, but I think it may also a good idea to have a look to other language Stack Exchange sites and see what they do with questions similar to this one.

@Charlie: Since you are the OP of the question mentioned in this post and a very experienced user of Spanish.SE, I would like to know your view about this.

The [tag:puns] tag exists in English.SE, German.SE (as [tag:wordplay]) and French.SE (as [tag:jeux-de-mots]), but not in Spanish.SE. I guess it can be added also here.

I just created the puns tag. When I'll have some spare time I will look back to older questions fitting this tag.

I think it would be a good idea to write a (short) answer so that people can vote if they agree with the fact of creating this tag.

I created the puns tag and I managed to tag 3 questions fitting this tag.
I think it would be advisable to have this tag since this kind of questions cannot be categorized well as being idioms.
